# Way to do mulitple substitutions on selection

Tags: visual-mode, substitute

When I visually select text and enter `:` I'll get this:

```
:'<,'>
```

Now I can enter a substitution to be done on those lines. However, what if I wanted to do several substitution, e.g. `foo` to `bar` and `hello` to `world`? What would I need to do then?

Comment: Fun fact!: `:*` is the same as `'<,'>`. e.g. `:%s/foo/bar/` -> `:*s/foo/bar/`

Comment: My example should be: `:'<,'>s/foo/bar/` -> `:*s/foo/bar/`

Comment: @PeterRincker I would actually consider this the best answer, because it's the least interruptive

Answer (score 5):

Using `gv` is a good option. Another alternative is to just hit <kbd>:</kbd>
<kbd>Up</kbd> after you do your first substitution. This will bring up your previous substitution with the `:'<,'>` text at the beginning.

Then, you can edit the previous command with your cursor keys and backspace.

This works because conveniently, the `:'<,'>` causes the substitution to be limited to your current *or previous* visual selection  if you don't have text visually selected at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your exact example case you can use `:Subvert` from Tim Pope's [abolish.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish).

```
:%S/{foo,hello}/{bar,world}/g
```

You can see this in action in the the [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Supercharged substitution with :Subvert](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/supercharged-substitution-with-subvert/)

Comment: +1 for Tim Pope's `abolish`.

Answer (score 3):

While there are probably ways to do it all in a single substitution, I think that probably the most *practical* way of doing it is simply:

1. Do the first substitution
2. Press <kbd>g</kbd> then <kbd>v</kbd> (this will select the previous visual selection)
3. Do the second substitution

See `:h gv` for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Define a dictionary containing your substitutions:

`let g:dict={'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'}`

Then you can substitute several items at once:

`'<,'>s/foo\|hello/\=get(dict, submatch(0))/g`

or even completly dynamic:

`exe "'<,'>s/". join(keys(dict), '\|'). '/\=get(dict,submatch(0))/g'`

This works also, if you want to replace at the same time foo by bar and bar by foo.

Comment: This seems to complicated to me to do during edit time. I'd much rather `'<,'>!sed 'do substitutions'`

Comment: @hgiesel you  can do that, but note, that multiline substitution is a lot trickier and also you can't use special RE features.